# XHR error (404 not Found) systemjs-angular-loader.js

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I recently had to migrate to a new development machine (windows 7 > windows 10).
I was using VS 2017 on both machines, FWIW.

Anyway, when I run this Angular project on the new machine I get the following:

---

```
/CableComplete/systemjs-angular-loader.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:391 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost/CableComplete/systemjs-angular-loader.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost/CableComplete/systemjs-angular-loader.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1075:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1370:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1388:17)
    Error loading http://localhost/CableComplete/systemjs-angular-loader.js
    Error loading http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/src/main.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1075:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1370:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1388:17)
    Error loading http://localhost/CableComplete/systemjs-angular-loader.js
    Error loading http://localhost/CableComplete/CableCompleteCli/src/main.js
```

---

I'm not sure exactly what went wrong in transition from one machine to the other... but this project was running fine in localhost on the other machine.

I checked some of the other solutions in SO related to this issue -- but none of them should work, because the project is the same on both machines -- nothing changed.

Maybe there is something wrong with a package via npm? I had to download all the packages to the new machine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe your global packages differ across environments. npm list -g --depth=0 - Here's how to config SystemJS at it's most basic level

Comment: npm list produced the following: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

Comment: Was it same on both machines?

Comment: No....

D:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@1.2.3
+-- npm@4.6.1
`-- typescript@2.2.0

Comment: Also, I find it interesting that the drive letter is different on each machine. is there an environment variable for Node.js that makes it open in D instead of C?

Comment: I would imagine that's where you ran the install command.

Comment: OK. Maybe its a problem -- because the project is located at D\Users... not C\Users.

Comment: @JGFMK, Do you have any thoughts on how to remedy this issue?

Comment: I'm a Mac user, so Windows is not my forte. My only thoughts were there were some global packages installed on your old machine that aren't on your new one. The other thing you could try doing is deleting node_modules folder and re-running npm init. Maybe something in there was pointing to wrong drive if you say that changed in the transition.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Installing cli and the packages globally resolved my issue. Thank you.